# How can I detect a "copy image" browser event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jquery, I can detect when the user copies something (like text) with ctrl-c or through the context menu:

```
$(document).on('copy',function(e){$('body').prepend('copy event <br>');});
```

However, the event doesn't seem to trigger when an image is copied. How can I detect image-copy? Specifically I'd like to detect copying from a `<canvas>` element, but any `<img>` should do as a starting point for understanding this problem.

Test scenario: http://jsfiddle.net/jm23xe8w/

Comment: This might help you: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/cutcopypaste.html

Comment: What is your goal of capturing this event?

Comment: @AlmaDo I need users to copy the image to their clipboard, then back to the browser - this will allow using pixel data from cross-site image origin images (without security risk, since it is an explicit user action to do it). So, when they initiate a copy event, I will enable the paste functionality to make it intuitive how it works.

Comment: But then - what if they will copy with browser main menu (edit/copy)?

Comment: @AlmaDo Ideally the event would be detected no matter how the user initiated the copy...

Comment: Using a modified version of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jm23xe8w/2/

I'm able to trigger the 'copy' event on the IMG, but only if you right click and select copy from there and only in IE11.  If you select the image in the DOM it stops working too.  I'm guessing it has something to do with the mixed media (text + image), but I can't explain why it's not firing in Chrome or Firefox at all.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers doesn't have copy images event,so you need to simulate it by some tricks.also clipboard doesn't save images in it.Clipboard only saves texts in itself.You need to convert images to a base64 encoded string then save it to clipboard and paste it on your app.But there is an issue with this that Are the clipboard data , the copied images or there are some another data of some another application in it.For this, you can add a unique string to your encoded string at first and or at end and check it wherever you want to paste it.For converting the images to base64encode string you can use this code :

```
function getImageData(img) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    var imgd = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    return imgd;
}
```

Pass the ‍‍‍‍`img` tag to this function to get your result.